# Produce a composed image with different sized layers with transparency

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I'm very new to Python and am exploring it's use to allow users to build custom images.  The idea is that the client would select a few options and the image would be created on the server then downloaded (or used for other things on the server side).

The image is composed of many images, most of which are small icon type of images that are irregular shapes and have transparency.  All layers are `.png` files.

I've tried using Pillow but it seems the image needs to be the same size as the overall image to properly use the transparency of the top layers.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
from PIL import Image

background = Image.open("Background.png")
foreground = Image.open("Trim.png")
fire = Image.open("Type_Fire_Large.png")

background = Image.alpha_composite(background, foreground)
background.paste(fire, (150, 150))
background.show()
```

The image looks like this:

[image: Layered image with black on overlay]

`Background.png` is the shaded "noise" and `Trim.png` is the grey diagonal lines.  The best part: `Trim.png` has the center transparent and is able to show `Background.png` in the middle.  But it's also the same size as the image.

The problem is `Fire`; notice how theres that black border (and odd fuchsia dot).  The documentation states that the overlay image needs to be the same size.  But it seems like a common scenario where someone would want to place a smaller icon with transparency on top of another image and compose them into one image.

I'm not attached to any particular library, I'm wide open to ideas and alternatives.  The only thing I'm trying to do is keep it simple, so creating an entire game engine or the like to produce an image would probably be too much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To just paste one png on top of another, respecting transparency, try

```
background.paste(fire, (x,y), fire.convert("RGBA"))
```

Comment: That was surprisingly easy and kind of undocumented. Thank you!

Comment: The odd fuscia dot implies that the PNG was already in RGBA mode, how did you figure this out?

Comment: @MarkRansom I just did Image.open() on a png with alpha channel and noticed that RGBA conversion was still necessary before I could use it as a mask.

Comment: PNG comes in two styles, paletted and true color. Only the paletted style needs to be converted to RGBA. Usually a paletted PNG only has a single transparent color, like a GIF. That's why I was surprised.

Comment: @MarkRansom That is a valid point, we don't really know if the conversion was necessary. Though looking at the images in the original post I would guess they're not in truecolor format as that would just be wasteful.

Comment: If your image is already in RGB mode, you can use
    img.paste(newImg.convert("RGB"), (0, 0), newImg)

Answer (score 2):

First I'd say Johannes Holmberg already answered your main concern: The missing transparency.

**But I can hopefully explain what it's about with that *odd fuchsia dot*:**

A transparent color image is usually stored as RGBA (RGB for Red, Green, Blue and A for `Alpha`). Here `Alpha` defines the transparency, from no transparency to full transparency.

Overlaying the images the correct way we see the GIMP Logo but the color stripe is almost invisible - because it's (almost) transparent.

[image: Using RGBA]

But - as every pixel *could be* possibly visible - **every** pixel does still have a color. Even those pixels with `100%` transparency. Thus, if we do not take `Alpha` into consideration we see each pixel color without transparency. This way we might have disturbing colors that are usually not disturbing at all - as long as they are fully transparent.

[image]

Comment: The dot reminded me of the days when I messed with Duke Nukem 3D and they used fuchsia as the color to be removed in the 2d sprites. It makes sense that they have a color even if they are transparent. I assume the dot was something either part of the save or was that color before I turned it transparent.   Thanks for the clarification and now I know!